# Finding a tangent function

Tags: calculus

> find function of the line with the slope 1 and is tangent to $y=\frac{7x-1}{x}$

If I derive $y=\frac{7x+1}{x}$  I get $y'=\frac{-1}{x^2}$ so for any value of $x$ the slope will not be $1$ meaning that I can not find the function of a tangent with a slope of 1?

Comment: I would say, $y'=\color{red}+\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: Sorry, mistake with the sign, it is $\frac{7x+1}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y=\frac{7x-1}{x}=7-x^{-1}$, we have
$$y'=0-(-1)x^{-2}=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Sorry, mistake with the sign, it is $\frac{7x+1}{x}$

Comment: @gbox: Then, we have $y'=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: And therefore we can not find the tangent function?

Comment: @gbox: There are no tangent lines whose slope is $1$.